# How can I start a new activity from my android code?

Tags: android-activity

I am totally new to android and I have a question that I would thank a lot if somebody can answer me.How can I start a new activity from my android code? For example if in my current activity, string x1 = string x2,   then I want to start new activity

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your new Activity is called **CoolActivity** then you do the following to start your activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CoolActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

for your reference: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: Thank you for answer, But the CoolActivity must be in the same package or it can be in the separate package?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create an other activity in your code?
Normally you only have one activity per view. If you want to start an other activity, you have to create an other file for exemple activity2.java
Add this activity in the manifest.xml like this:

```
   <activity
        android:name=".activity2"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" />
```

And in the beginning of your activity2.java, start with something like that:

```
public class Activity2 extends Activity{
```

I don't if i answered your question or not ...

Comment: Thank you for answer, But the CoolActivity must be in the same package or it can be in the separate package?

Comment: I think the CoolActivity can be in a separate package, you just have to import the package of the CoolActivity in the activity which calls it.